# Is it expected that a custom component derived from InputNumber<T> only binds one-way?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a simple custom Blazor component inheriting from InputNumber<T> to contain an input element and some other conveniences (I stripped the extras out here for simplicity).

The problem I had was that the property binding only worked one-way to the component. I have a simple demo with this custom component and a simple input element, bound to the same property. When the input element is used to alter the value, this is repeated in the custom component but when the custom component is used the change never makes it back to the bound property (or the input element).

After a lot of digging I came up with an unsatisfactory (to me) solution which involved copying some framework classes (InputNumber<T> and InputBase<T>) and adding change notifications to the Value property setter in InputBase<T> as below:

Previous definition:

```
    [Parameter]
    public TValue? Value
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

Modified definition:

```
    [Parameter]
    public TValue? Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(_value, value)) return;

            _value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            var fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(ValueExpression);
            EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
        }
    }
    private TValue? _value;
```

NB much of the framework code is marked as internal so I actually had to copy/paste 4 classes into my project as below in order to get it to compile.

[image: Copied/modified framework classes]

I can't help feeling that I've misunderstood something fundamental: I can't understand why InputNumber<T> wouldn't participate in change notifications by default.

Have I missed the point?

Here are my two components and test page:

### InputNumberComponent.razor - my original input component

Only binds one-way-to-component.

```
@inherits InputNumber<T>
@typeparam T

<input type="number" id="@Id" @bind-value="@Value" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Id{ get; set; }
}
```

### InputNumberHack.razor - the modified input component

Binds two-way. **InputNumberCopy<T>** is the modified framework class, which inherits in turn from **InputBaseCopy<T>**, which is where I modified the Value property.

```
@inherits InputNumberCopy<T>
@typeparam T

<input type="number" id="@Id" @bind-value="@Value" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Id{ get; set; }
}
```

### InputTest.razor - the test page.

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorBindingTest.Client.Components

<PageTitle>Input Test</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model="this">
    <h1>Pair 1 (only binds one-way to the component)</h1>

    <div>Simple input bound to local value 1</div>
    <input type="number" @bind-value="LocalValue1" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

    <div>Custom input bound to local value 1</div>
    <InputNumberComponent Id="lv" @bind-Value="LocalValue1" />


    <h1 class="mt-4">Pair 2 - hacked InputNumber base (binds two-way to the component)</h1>

    <div>Simple input bound to local value 2</div>
    <input type="number" @bind-value="LocalValue2" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

    <div>Custom input bound to local value 2</div>
    <InputNumberHack Id="lv" @bind-Value="LocalValue2" />
</EditForm>

@code {
    public decimal LocalValue1 { get; set; } = 0m;
    public decimal LocalValue2 { get; set; } = 0m;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding to the wrong property/field.  `Value` is a component `[Parameter]`, so treated correctly as read only, which is what you are seeing.  `CurrentValueAsString` is the read/write `protected` field that you need to use.  It's wired up into all the internal notification and validation processes.

```
@inherits InputNumber<T>
@typeparam T

<input type="number" id="@Id" @bind-value="@CurrentValueAsString" @bind-value:event="oninput" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Id{ get; set; }
}
```

If you want to see what's going on here's the code for [InputNumber](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputNumber.cs) and the code for [InputBase](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs).

Comment: I wrote a long comment which probably didn't make sense, so instead I'm going to say: thanks MrC! It looks like you've pointed out the key point, which is that the html input element needs to be bound to a *string* property, and a good candidate for that is CurrentValueAsString, as you pointed out. This now works. Phew!

Comment: Have you replaced your original `InputNumberComponent` with my updated code and run your Test Page?  All the `string` to `T` and `T` to `string` conversions, notifications and event raising is handled by the Input control.

Comment: @Jon .  Our comments crossed, I was in the middle of typing a reply and got distracted.  As I said above, `CurrentValueAsString` is all wired correctly.

Comment: Yes sorry about that - my first comment was a bit misguided. I didn't appreciate that it was the value bound with the html element that was the issue here (and the value bound to the custom control containing it is still nice and typed)